# Get values from pandas PeriodIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following PeriodIndex:

```
PeriodIndex(['2018Q3', '2018Q4', '2019Q1', '2019Q2'], dtype='period[Q-MAR]', name='Quarter', freq='Q-MAR')
```

How do I extract the values i.e. `['2018Q3', '2018Q4', '2019Q1', '2019Q2']`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to `string`s and then to `list`:

```
p = pd.PeriodIndex(['2018Q3', '2018Q4', '2019Q1', '2019Q2'], 
                    dtype='period[Q-MAR]', name='Quarter', freq='Q-MAR')


print (p.astype(str).tolist())
['2018Q3', '2018Q4', '2019Q1', '2019Q2']
```